# Can we say a convex cone is a closed set without further proof?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis

There are some related problems:
1. [dual cone is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810213/dual-cone-is-closed)
2. [Why is any subspace a convex cone?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168898/why-is-any-subspace-a-convex-cone)

Consider a cone $\mathcal{C}(A)$:

$$\mathcal{C}(A) = \{Ax: x\geq 0\}$$

This is a cone generated by the columns of $A$. Since $x\geq 0$, the construction meets the definition of being a convex cone.  Therefore $\mathcal{C}(A)$ is a convex cone.

Is it closed?

I think it is without further proof.

---

However, in the following lecture from Stanford:

http://web.stanford.edu/class/msande310/lecture03.pdf  (p.9 and p.11)

In the proof of Farkas lemma, the author cannot guarantee that $\mathcal{C}$ is closed convex before further proof.  So the author utilize convergence sequence to prove that.

Comment: Why do you think it is?

Comment: You should find out what closed means in this context. E.g. are linear combinations of vectors from the cone part of the cone.

Comment: Why I think it is....this is from the following lecture from Upenn: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/convex1-09.pdf  Definition 3.2.4

Comment: $C$ is a convex cone iff $C$ is closed under positive linear combination

Comment: This is what confuses me. If it is from definition, we do not have to prove it further.

Comment: Just a fussy detail:  What type of object is $A$?  (I presume that is a linear map from a finite dimensional vector space to a finite dimensional vector space.  However, if "linear", "finite", and "finite" in that sentence are not correct then we might need to be careful with "closed".)

Comment: $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$

Comment: In this context "closed" is used in the topological sense: a subset of a topological space is closed if its complement is an open subset. So there is indeed something to be proved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closedness of $\{A\,x \mid x \ge 0\}$ is proved on p. 11 of http://web.stanford.edu/class/msande310/lecture03.pdf.

However, there are convex cones, that are not closed, e.g. $C = (0,\infty)^2 \cup \{(0,0)\}$ is a convex cone in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is not closed.

Comment: The link is broke.

Comment: Other proofs can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1831401/58577